# codeigniter dropdown with ajax and jquery console returns "NetworkError: 404 Not Found via firebug console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Please help a loafer. Am trying to populate a dropdown that is dependent on the first. The first is for state, when it is changed, the city should be populated. I have followed various tutorials online(some from stakeoverflow) and am stuck. I have very little knowledge of ajax and jquery. On top of that, am new to codeigniter. Below are my codes

Model for state

```
public function get_list(){

    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    $return = array();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($result->result_array() as $row) {
            $return[$row['sid']] = $row['state'];
        }
    }

    return $return;

}
```

Model for city

```
public function get_cities($state = null){

         $this->db->select('ctid, city');

         if($state != NULL){
            $this->db->where('state_id', $state);
         }

             $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

             $cities = array();

         if($query->result()){
             foreach ($query->result() as $cit) {
             $cities[$cit->ctid] = $cit->city;
         }
            return $cities;
         }else{
            return FALSE;
         }
}
```

My controller

```
public function index()
{

    $data['state_option'] = $this->State_model->get_list();
    $this->load->view('_parts/header');
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    $this->load->view('_parts/footer');
}
public function dependent_dropdown($state)
{

     header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
     echo(json_encode($this->city_model->get_cities($state)));
}
```

my jquery/ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#state').change(function(){
        // $("#city").html("<option>Loading...</option>");
        $('#city > option').remove();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        if (state != "") {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:'state',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('site/dependent_dropdown'); ?>"+state,
            success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $('#city').append("<option value='"+data.city+"'>"+data.city+"</option>");
              });
             }

          });
      }
      else{
        $('#city').html('<option>--Select City--</option>');
      }
      });
   });
```

my view (state dropdown)

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="" selected>--Select State--</option>
        <?php foreach ($state_option as $state) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $state ?>"><?php echo $state; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

(city dropdown)

```
<select id="city" name="city" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="" selected>--Select City--</option>

              </select>
```

Comment: Which URL is getting hit when you change city ? Have you checked this through inspect element ?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/ci/site/dependent_dropdownStateName 404 Not Found
  227ms`   
It hits the above url with the name of the state selected and 404 Not found.

Comment: I think because you have not set your base url on config.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983, am using site_url(), so I don't need to set that. However, on your request I did it and nothing changed.
I removed `+state` I appended on the url and it returned 200 ok but with a different error `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
 

typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;` And it's still not fetching the cities.

Comment: Just a note: if your using CI 3 versions and up it is recommended. `WARNING: You MUST set this value!` what it says in config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem eventually. I changed my view to display data for state like so

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="" selected>--Select State--</option>
        <?php foreach ($state_option as $state_id => $state) { ?>
          <option id="state" value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>"><?php echo $state; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Then I changed my ajax call like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#state').change(function(){
        $('#city').html('<option>Loading....</option>');
        var state = $('#state').val();
        if (state != "") {
          $.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/dependent_dropdown/"+state).success(function(data){
              $('#city > option').remove();                
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              for(var i in data){
                $('#city').append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>");
              }

          })

      }
      else{
        $('#city').html('<option>--Select City--</option>');
      }
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ajax request,  change

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('site/dependent_dropdown'); ?>"+state,
```

To

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('site/dependent_dropdown'); ?>/"+state,
```

Comment: thanks, I did like you said, no visible errors but city dropdown is still not populated. It's returned blank.

Comment: Was list of state returned from the server?

Comment: Additionally, it returned "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (length-1) in obj;"

Comment: Yes, list of state was returned. Am beginning to think if something is wrong with my sql query?

Comment: where did you get that error?  

       "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (length-1) in obj;"

Comment: From the firebug console

Comment: I also asked when the list of state was returned as ajax response
If you get that error along with the response, then javascript cant use that as object because it would be invalid json data

Comment: Try screen snap the response let me see

Comment: However, firebug is showing response as false after the line below

`POST http://localhost/ci/site/dependent_dropdown/StateName
 
200 OK
  509m`